# Linked List Delete and insertAfter Method

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I am having trouble with delete and insertAfter methods, the methods are to perform the action and return a boolean if the action was a success(true) or not(false). The InsertAfter method will insert a string but always in the same spot, and Delete method will always delete the same node.

```
private class StrNode {

        String data;
        StrNode next;
    }

    private StrNode head;   // the head of the singly-linked list.

    public StringList() {
        head = null;
    }

public void prepend(String s) {                                                         
        var newNode = new StrNode();
        // TODO: Adds an item to the start of the list.     
        newNode.data = s;
        if(head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
        }
        
    }

/**
     * Inserts an item after the first instance of a key if the key exists.
     *
     * @param s the item to insert
     * @param key the item in the list to insert after
     * @return whether the insertion was successful
     */
    public boolean insertAfter(String s, String key) {                                                      
        // TODO:    Inserts an item after the first instance of a key if the key exists.
        var newNode = new StrNode();
        StrNode current = head;
        newNode.data = s;
        
        if(head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else if(current == newNode.next){
            current.next = newNode;
            current = newNode;

        }
        else {
            newNode.next = current.next;
            current.next = newNode;
        }
        
        
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Deletes the first instance of an item from the list.
     *
     * @param key the value of the item to delete from the list.
     * @return whether the deletion was successful.
     */
    public boolean delete(String key) {                                                     
        // TODO:    Deletes the first instance of an item from the list.
        StrNode current = head;
        StrNode sucNode = current;
        
        if(current == null) {
            sucNode = head.next;
            head = sucNode;
            return true;
        }
        else if(current.next != null) {
            sucNode = current.next.next;
            current.next = sucNode;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

the main method I am wanting to insert four after three which should be: three, two, four, one.
but I get: three, four, two, one

the delete method just deletes the four which should actually look like: three, four, two
but I get: three, two, one
main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        StringList s = new StringList();
        
        s.prepend("one");
        s.prepend("two");
        s.prepend("three");
        System.out.println(s);
        
        s.insertAfter("four", "three");
        System.out.println(s);
        
        System.out.println(s.delete("one"));
        System.out.println(s);
        
        
    }
```

Comment: I thought I saw this question yesterday. Are you posting it again? I clearly remember the prepend() method, which strikes me as an odd method name. I would have used addFirst(). At any rate, you should include the code for the prepend() method because this is how you're setting things up.

Comment: yeah my bad, i thought i would make things more clear just to see the methods I am trying out thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about two methods:

#### `insertAfter`

Some issues:

- You don't use the argument `key`.
- In case `head` is null, you can never satisfy the condition that the node should be inserted *after* a node with a key, so in that case you should return false.
- `current` is initialised as `head`, so you are assigning the new node to `head.next` without checking the `key` matches...
- You always return `false`, never `true`

You should look for the given key by iterating over the list:

```
public boolean insertAfter(String s, String key) {
    // Inserts an item after the first instance of a key if the key exists.
    StrNode current = head;
    
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.data == key) { // found the insertion spot
            var newNode = new StrNode();
            newNode.data = s;
            newNode.next = current.next;
            current.next = newNode;
            return true;
        }
        current = current.next; // need to walk along the list
    }
    return false; // didn't find the key
}
```

#### `delete`

- You don't use the argument `key`.
- In case `head` (is `current`) is null, you can never satisfy the condition that the node to delete should have the given key, so in that case you should return false.
- In the other case, you are always deleting the second node without checking the `key` matches...

Corrected:

```
public boolean delete(String key) {                                                     
    // Deletes the first instance of an item from the list.
    StrNode current = head;
    if (head == null) return false;
    if (head.data == key) {
         head = head.next;
         return true;
    }

    while (current.next != null) {
        if (current.next.data == key) { // found it
            current.next = current.next.next; // delete it
            return true;
        }
        current = current.next; // need to walk along the list
    }
    return false; // not found
}
```

### Remark about `prepend`:

You don't need the `if` statement. The code in the `else` block works fine when `head` is null, so your code can just be:

```
public void prepend(String s) { 
    // Adds an item to the start of the list. 
    StrNode node = new StrNode();
    node.data = s;
    node.next = head;
    head = node;
}
```